# saving R list into a text file

Tags: r, list, save

i am using R to do analysis on some matrix. When i tried to save a long  list which looks like something keep repeating like this

```
$M0004_1.02

  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]

A   15    3    2    2    0    6   16   49

C   72    1   87   97    1   63   77    7

G    8   95   11    1   99   14    1   30

T    6    1    0    0    0   18    6   14
```

to a text file, either the 
`$M0004_1.02` is missing or words are quoted by "", how can save these?

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work?

Comment: thank you for your response, i have tried write.table but it automatically groups the column and rows , i also tried cat but it does not work on list object.

Answer (score 1):

`write.table` applies for usual statistical data (rectangular: data.frames or matrices).
For other types of objects you can use `save` and use .rda format or `dput` for an ascii representation.
In the first case, you will have to use `load` to restore the saved object, know that he will have the first given name. 
For `dput`, you restore the object with `dget`.

Comment: thank you very much, the original list was actually a saved R list object, what i am trying to do is to somehow print that list as shown in the R console to a text file,  i tried the dput but that didnt quite do the job. thanks anyways.

Comment: Ohhh.. OK Have a look at `capture.output` and at `sink`